# Converting downloaded PDF/HTML files to CSV in Python

Tags: python, loops, pdf, web-scraping, glob

I have a code that downloads some PDFs from a list of links, however when I try to loop through the downloaded files and convert them into a CSV, glob is not recognizing any files in the directory.

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import tabula

# Create list of urls and file names 
urls = [('URL1', 'https://www.health.ny.gov/statistics/sparcs/reports/compliance/2023/c2023_sub012023_000401.pdf'),
        ('URL2', 'https://www.health.ny.gov/statistics/sparcs/reports/compliance/2022/c2022_sub012023_000401.pdf')]

# Loop through urls and download PDF files 
path = 'mypath'
os.chdir(path)
def url_response(url):
    path, url = url
    r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for ch in r:
            f.write(ch)
for x in urls:
    url_response(x)

mypath2 = 'mypath\*.csv'
for f in glob.glob(mypath2):
    tabula.convert_into(f, f + '.csv', output_format = 'csv', pages = 'all')
```

Comment: Have you tried `mypath2 = "mypath\*.pdf" to iterate over the pdf files you are trying to convert? You probably do not have any `csv` file there yet.

Comment: Good question.  I should've clarified - I've tried nearly every type of file extension.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Actually, since their name do not contain an extension, that's not a surprise. Your files are called `URL1` and `URL2` as per your code. So probably try either naming them `URL1.pdf` and `URL2.pdf` and globing on `*.pdf` or staying with these names and globing on : `glob.glob("mypath/**.*")` (but you'll get every single path in that folder)